# Editing PDF in nodejs - problem with xref

Tags: node.js, pdf, node-modules, pdf-lib.js

I got a pdf, where I have to put some datas inside (like addresses and images).
At the end, I need to sign it with a certificate (so, if I opened it with a reader, I got the sidebar with the info about that sign and about that PDF hasn't been modified)
Like this image
[![PDF TABLE][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J45F2.png

I'm using pdf-lib but I cannot add "the certificate" with node-signpdf, due to a problem with xref.

`Expected xref at NaN but found other content.`

Is there a way to correct this problem?
Is not important using the same library.
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the xref table is malformed. Run the PDF file through cpdf or qpdf or pdftk to mend it. For example, in cpdf, `cpdf in.pdf -o out.pdf` will do.